# Batch Script to Loop through SVN changed files

Tags: batch-file, svn

So I have a post-commit hook which triggers a build on our Jenkins server. Everything is working, except when I try and loop through the changed files in an SVN repo. The issue is that the commit actually hangs, if I comment out the loop, where the changed files are noted, then the commit completes successfully.

I googled the SVN diff command which seems to be what I want, comparing the current revision to the HEAD revision. It works on the command line with hard coded values, but not in my loop with the %1% and %2% which get populated from SVN itself.

My code so far:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

SET REPOS=%1%
SET TXN=%2%

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('svnlook author -r !TXN! !REPOS!') do set AUTH_NAME=%%a
SET EMAILS="!AUTH_NAME!"@gmail.com

SET /a OLDTXN=!TXN! - 1

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('svn diff --summarize -r !OLDTXN!:!TXN! <repo URL>') do (
    set FILES=%%a
    rem python D:\csvn\data\repositories\Test\hooks\compile_file.py !FILES!
)
```

Where "repo URL" is the root repo in SVN I hard code in, which is fine.
Now for example if I comment out the SET TXN line and replace it with a hard coded numeric value such as:

```
SET TXN=518
```

The the loop works and I get the desired emails with the correct files that have changed, so it must be something around how the TXN gets passed from SVN into the batch script. It might not be populating as I think.

The python script is commented out and just accepts the file as a command line argument and emails it to a DL. This works, again, with hard coded TXN value as above. Obviously my loop is preventing the commit finishing successfully but not sure what I'm doing wrong. But I am pretty sure it's related to the TXN variable for the reasons mentioned above.

Any help on my issue would be greatly appreciated :)

Edit * Changed variables from %% to !! as I'm using enabledelayedexpansion *

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now resolved - if anyone is looking at this for future reference, the issue was decrementing the TXN variable that SVN passed in. To get the changes since the last commit I used a different SVN command, instead of the diff command.